# Rails + EventMachine application open source apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eventmachine

I want to play with EventMachine in Rails and I've been reading any EventMachine related article I can get my hands on. Most of them feature a simple standalone example of EM, so I'm looking to find a full feldged open source app with EM to take apart. Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many full applications that make use of Eventmachine, Search Github for it. Here's an interesting one that uses Twitter's streaming API with Eventmachine: https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream

Comment: I tried searching for it and didn't find anything good, hence my question.

Comment: Did you check out tweetstream? :)

Comment: Actually you're right tweetstream is great, first it didn't make sense, but once I understood eventmachine in detail, it did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an example application of using Rails3, EventMachine and Fibers to do async work.  You can see it at https://github.com/igrigorik/async-rails.

Comment: I did see it, but it was a bit too simplistic for me. I understand how it works, I just want to see best practices of integrating it into a Rails app.